# remove cells with zero value in all dimension from processing

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix F with 200 rows and columns and 4 in the third dimension. many cells of this matrix are zero in all dimensions. I have written a code that is stated with reading cells. I want in this code cells that have zero value in all dimensions not to be read. for example something like below:

```
for i=1:200
     for j=1:200
      if F(i,j,1)~=0 & F(i,j,2)~=0 & F(i,j,3)~=0 & F(i,j,4)~=0
       ....
       ....
       ...
      end
end
```

Thank you.

Comment: What's wrong with your code? Seems to work fine. I would just replace `&` by `&&` since you're not doing "bitwise and".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: Are you looking for something like this?

```
if ~all(F(i,j,:) == 0)
...
end
```

Comment: Thank you. no this code remove all cells with zero value from processing but I want only  cells that are common in all dimension and have zero value remove from processing.

Comment: Did you actually try this? It does the same thing as your code. (if you place it withing the for loops)

Comment: I try that but my code is like Oseiskar code `(all(F(i,j,:)~=0)`. it removes all cells with zero value. but I want only cells that are common in all dimensions and have zero values.

Comment: Ok, now I think I got what you meant, edited the answer

Comment: I wrote it but I got the error: **??? if !all(F(i,j,:)==0)** **Error: Unexpected MATLAB operator.**

Comment: Sorry, tested that only in Octave, now changed `!` to `~`